# Which AngularCLI version to use for Angular 5 Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to create an Angular 5 project, but when I download Angular CLI it creates Angular 6 projects. How can I create Angular 5 project with which version of Angular CLI

Comment: CLI version 1.7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to downgrade to angular 5, Angular-CLI version should be `1.7.4`

```
  npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
  npm cache clean
  npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4
```

Refer [**`angular-cli/node-js/typescript/rxjs/compatiblity matrix`**](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)

Comment: Is there any docs that support that Angular CLI 1.7.4 create Angular 5 project?

Comment: I could not find any comment where it is mentioned that Angular CLI 1.7.4 supports Angular 5. Can you please tell where to check this?

Comment: Why don't you install the mentioned version of CLI , generate a new application and observe dependency section of package.json

Comment: I did check some more blogs and found even Angular CLI 1.6.8 will create Angular 5 project. Do you have anything about this.

Comment: Well yeah are you aware of the concept of [semantic versioning](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/12/let-me-explain-angular-release-cycles/) CLI version `1.6.8` would undoubtedly generate new Angular 5 project but with every upgrade  CLI tool consist of new features and minor bug fixes  [what's new with cli 1.7](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/02/19/angular-cli-1.7/) that's why you should stick to the latest version i.e `1.7.4`

Comment: Mark it if it helped

Comment: Does there any problem to upgrade that cli to 15 version ? cause I'm using node 16 and angular/cli@1.7.4 is not adapted to that node version.

Comment: @famas23 Refer this https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3